# shebang not working on WSL (Windows Subsystem Linux)

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows-subsystem-for-linux, shebang

I installed WSL (Ubuntu 18.04) on Windows 10 to use instead of using parallel 2 OS. However, when I was using shebang, I couldn't run the script named `test_file.py` successfully. First, I created a folder named `test_project`. In this folder, I created:

- An `src` folder that contains a simple Python script is shown as follows

  ```py
  #!/usr/bin/env python3                 
  print("Hello world")
  ```
- A Python environment folder named `environment` through `python3 -m venv environment/` (I'm using Python 3.6)

The problem is when I stepped into the environment and typed some commands like in the attached picture [Run python file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ta7fa.png), the program ran "command not found" although I already used shebang at the beginning of the code.

Apart from that, I also changed `#!/usr/bin/env` to `#!/usr/bin/python3` and escape the environment, it didn't work as well. Only when I type `Python3 test_file.py` it worked.

Has anyone faced this problem before? Can anyone explain to me why this happens? I'm wondering whether it is different between using WSL compared to Ubuntu in this case, or I was missing some steps during coding. I know that this problem is debated common previously, however I couldn't find any source that can tackle my problem. I really appreciate all your help.

Comment: Are you still looking for help with this one?  When you are in your venv (`environment`), does running `python3` by itself work?  What does `command -v python3` show?  Also, you mentioned `Python3 test_file.py` -- Is that supposed to be uppercase or is that a type?  Thanks!

Comment: What you're doing wouldn't have worked on actual Linux/Unix either; in Linux/Unix, the shell doesn't search for executables in your current directory by default. You need to prefix the executable with `./` to execute a script in the current directory. So in your example, you have to do `./test_file.py`.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue and resolved it by the changing the line endings from CRLF which is native to Windows to LF which is what the shell is expecting.

You can do this with the `dos2unix` command:

```
dos2unix -b test_file.py
```

You'll probably need to install `dos2unix` on some newer distributions.

There are [other methods](https://phoenixnap.com/kb/convert-dos-to-unix) that can be used as well.

Comment: Good first answer!  That probably was what the OP was running into.  I've added the "how to" part to your answer for completeness.  Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for your solution. It seems to be that WSL still lacks or differs from a complete Ubuntu, not only in some simple examples but also in other stuff like building systems (thread, processes) or some built-in third-party library, and so on. Then I decided to use Ubuntu as the main OS instead.